# How can i download rds file from dropbox in r?

Tags: r, download, dropbox

I need easy way to download rds file without log in from dropbox to R. Here is my dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/exyy0i0tqq99q0w/test.rds?dl=0

Comment: Replace the `dl=0` with `raw=1`. So try `download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/exyy0i0tqq99q0w/test.rds?raw=1", "test.rds")` and then `readRDS("test.rds")`

Comment: It works with dl = 0. Is it expected?

Comment: I would not have expected that, but if that works too then that's great.